# android: external allocation too large for this process -- where?

Tags: android, memory, allocation

I am getting the following error messages:

```
07-13 11:02:05.519: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(1605): 290314-byte external allocation too large for this process.

07-13 11:02:05.519: ERROR/(1605): VM won't let us allocate 290314 bytes

07-13 11:02:05.549: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(1605): 292612-byte external allocation too large for this process.

07-13 11:02:05.549: ERROR/(1605): VM won't let us allocate 292612 bytes
```

Is there any way to trace that back or get a stack trace or something that will show where that allocation is attempting to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, put a try/catch block around the suspected code, making sure to catch `Error e`, not `Exception e`, then `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch.

Comment: So what was the problem?  Don't leave us hanging! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Allocation Tracker** utility. Check out this article:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc